# Umbraco how to stop Rich Text Box to automatically add <p> tag in html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, umbraco, rte

I am developing a website in umbraco, the problem is when i insert my html in rich text editor it automatically inserts "p" (Paragraph Tag) tag in the html which is destroying my design.Please help me, i am stuck here.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: should i place the html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you adding the page field onto your markup? Through a view or as a pagefield?

If you're adding it as a pagefield add the attribute stripParagraph="true"

If you're adding in a view then you could try

Html.Raw(library.RemoveParagraphTags(Model.bodyText.ToString()))

But that will only remove the first one

You could roll your own version of that method to remove all P tage, or try what's suggested here  - http://scottsdevblog.com/2011/08/get-rid-of-those-pesky-p-tags-in-umbracos-tinymce-editor/

Comment: Should add - I've not tried what Scott suggests, I would typically use a Simple Editor or Textbox Multiple data type if I didn't want P tags (which might also work for you)

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked how to stop the paragraph tags from being inserted.  All of the proposed answers fail to prevent the insertion; they just try to mitigate its existence.

In your `\config\tinyMceConfig.config`, set `forced_root_block` to `false`.

`<customConfig>
    ...
    <config key="force_p_newlines">false</config>
    <config key="forced_root_block">false</config>
    ...
  </customConfig>`

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.Raw(richtexteditor.itsvalue) or check the [html agility pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/htmlagilitypack) on nuget.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I have had some trouble with this issue too and have a neat little solution that I wanted to share.

I tried changing / removing the forced_root_block and using Raw HTML, neither of which really worked well for me.

Instead I wrapped the output of the field in a semantic tag () and then added a css rule:

```
mce p:first-of-type {
    margin-top:0px;
}

mce p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

For me, this felt less 'hacky' and didn't require me to keep any customised versions of files or output mark-up in the Raw format.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco 7, Razor

@Umbraco.Field("yourDocumentPropertyAliasName", removeParagraphTags:true)